# dropdown values hide show

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 dropdowns, here is the fiddle,

https://jsfiddle.net/oqsf7gjq/1/

```
<select id="ddlOption">
<option value="">- Select an option -</option>
<option value="1">Yes</option>
<option value="2">No</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<select id="ddlCar">
<option value="">- Please select a name -</option>
<option value="1">Volvo</option>
<option value="2">Saab</option>
<option value="3">Mercedes</option>
<option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

When user selects "Yes" from "ddlOption" dropdown, then I want to show only 2 values (Saab and Audi) for dropdown "ddlCar" and when user selects "No", then I want to see all values for "ddlCar" dropdown.

Please suggest me any possibilities with Jquery code. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you rebind ddlCar dropdown based in ddlOption value instead of show/hide some value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tested in Edge, Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer 11**

Note that hiding and showing the options doesn't work in Edge or IE. The elements need to be really removed.

```js
$(function() {

  var $ddlCar = $("#ddlCar");
  var $ddlCarOptions = $ddlCar.children("option");

  $("#ddlOption").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "1") {
      $ddlCarOptions.filter(".toggleable").attr("selected", false).remove();
    } else {
      $ddlCar.empty().append($ddlCarOptions);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="ddlOption">
  <option value="">- Select an option -</option>
  <option value="1">Yes</option>
  <option value="2">No</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<select id="ddlCar">
  <option value="">- Please select a name -</option>
  <option class="toggleable" value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option class="toggleable" value="3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/oqsf7gjq/14/)**

```
$("#ddlOption").change(function() {
    $("#ddlCar").val("").find("[value=1], [value=3]").toggle( this.value==="2" );
});
```

```js
$("#ddlOption").change(function() {
  $("#ddlCar").val("").find("[value=1], [value=3]").toggle( this.value==="2" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlOption">
  <option value="">- Select an option -</option>
  <option value="1">Yes</option>
  <option value="2">No</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<select id="ddlCar">
  <option value="">- Please select a name -</option>
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Toggle the desired `option` elements by checking Boolean the first select's value (`this.value==="2"`)

Also, reset to `.val("")` in order to make sure the second select value is properly cleared from *possible* previous changes.

Comment: on select of "No", I want to see all values for "ddlCar" dropdown. Is there any shortcut method to show all as I have more than 300 items for "ddlCar" dropdown

Comment: @user584018 yes. Use the above script.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('#ddlOption').change(function(){
        var txt = $(this).val();
        alert(txt);
        if(txt==1){
        $('#ddlCar option[value="1"]').hide();
        $('#ddlCar option[value="3"]').hide();
        }
        else{
        $('#ddlCar option[value="1"]').show();
        $('#ddlCar option[value="3"]').show();
        }
     });
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ue4Cm/38/

Answer (score 1):

Check **updated** [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/oqsf7gjq/13/)

In your markup, you need to add classes to the dropdown values first

```
<select id="ddlOption">
<option value="">- Select an option -</option>
<option value="1">Yes</option>
<option value="2">No</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<select id="ddlCar">
<option value="">- Please select a name -</option>
<option value="1">Volvo</option>
<option value="2" class="yes">Saab</option>
<option value="3">Mercedes</option>
<option value="4" class="yes">Audi</option>
</select>
```

In your jquery code now

```
$(function() {
    $("#ddlOption").change(function() {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        if (selectedValue == 1)
        {
          $("#ddlCar option").hide();
          $("#ddlCar option.yes").show();
        }
        else
        {
          $("#ddlCar option").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: on select of "No", I want to see all values for "ddlCar" dropdown. Is there any shortcut method to show all as I have more than 300 items for "ddlCar" dropdown

Comment: @user584018 that is precisely what my code is doing. It is showing all values when No is selected. This line is the shortcut `$("#ddlCar option").show();`

Answer (score 0):

please check the code below I have made few changes to your code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function populateList() {
if($("option:selected",$("#ddlOption")).val()=="1")
{
    $(".val1").hide();
    $(".val2").show();
}
else if($("option:selected",$("#ddlOption")).val()=="2")
{
    $(".val1").show();
    $(".val2").hide();
}
else
{
    $(".val1").show();
    $(".val2").show();
}
}
</script>

<select id="ddlOption" onchange="populateList();">
<option value="">- Select an option -</option>
<option value="1">Yes</option>
<option value="2">No</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<select id="ddlCar">
<option value="">- Please select a name -</option>
<option value="1" class="val2">Volvo</option>
<option value="2" class="val1">Saab</option>
<option value="3" class="val2">Mercedes</option>
<option value="4" class="val1">Audi</option>
</select>
```

let me know if you have any doubts

Comment: please check link above

Comment: someone please correct my answer section i am new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can write code as below which is also works for larger object value(300 or whatever size) and it is dynamic.
Here optionOne, optionTwo are object which is bind when Yes/No value selected

[Updated Js fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/oqsf7gjq/16/)

```
$(function() {
var optionOne=[{text:"Saab",value:"2"},{text:"Audi",value:"4"}];

var optionTwo=[{text:"Volvo",value:"1"},{text:"Saab",value:"2"},{text:"Mercedes",value:"3"},{text:"Audi",value:"4"}];

$("#ddlOption").change(function() {

var selectedValue=$(this).val();

$('#ddlCar').html('');

var mySelect = $('#ddlCar').append($('<option></option>').val("").html("- Please select a name -"));

if(selectedValue==='1'){
$.each(optionOne, function(index, item) {
    mySelect.append($('<option></option>').val(item.value).html(item.text));
});
}else if(selectedValue==='2'){
$.each(optionTwo, function(index, item) {
    mySelect.append($('<option></option>').val(item.value).html(item.text));
});
}else{
//To Do if no selection
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/oqsf7gjq/17/ not the cleanest solution but it will work cross browsing.

```js
$(function() {
  var carArray = [];
  $('#ddlCar option').each(function() {
    carArray.push($(this));
  });

  $("#ddlOption").change(function() {
    if ($('#ddlOption').val() == 1) {
      $('#ddlCar option').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != 2 && $(this).val() != 4) {
          $(this).remove();
        }
      })
    } else {
      $('#ddlCar option').each(function() {
        $(this).remove();
      })
      for (var i in carArray) {
        $('#ddlCar').append(carArray[i])
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlOption">
  <option value="">- Select an option -</option>
  <option value="1">Yes</option>
  <option value="2">No</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<select id="ddlCar">
  <option value="0">- Please select a name -</option>
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```